# Java, why are objects known as instances of a class?

Tags: java, class, object

Classes are a software bundle of variables and functions, also known as a blueprint that defines the variables and methods common to objects of a certain kind. So why are objects also known as instances of a class?

Comment: Because that's the OOP terminology that was decided upon, and not just specific to Java.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on https://english.stackexchange.com/ ? It's a vocabulary question.

Comment: Why are instances of a class also called objects?

Comment: Also, classes don't have functions, they have methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, class is a blueprint; objects are made using those blueprints.

Its like you have a blueprint of a car - you have one blueprint, but many cars based on that blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

According to dictionary.com: An instance is - "an example or single occurrence of something"

An object is a single occurrence or realization of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Class is a syntactic notion, governed by compile time rules, such as naming, scope, etc. That your program defines a class A means that 1) you have a type, and 2) that the right class loader will be able to find A's bytecode on the classpath. But it doesn't mean that your running program is able to operate on this class. An operable object with its own state must be first instantiated with new, which, at run time, will cause the classloader to allocate memory required to hold that state. You can have any number of objects of a single class A, all of type A but with their own state memory.